# How to horizontal scrolling in BBEdit

Tags: macos, mac, bbedit

Horizontal scrolling in Modern MacOS is easy: simply hold down the Shift key and use the mouse wheel. However, that doesn't work in BBEdit. As I'm often using an external monitor, keyboard, and mouse (and usually turn off the built-in monitor), I don't use the trackpad very much. How can I enable horizontal scrolling with the mouse wheel in BBEdit